# In Jmeter how to pass beanshell sampler result to Thread group

Tags: performance, jmeter

In Bean shell sampler I am getting the line count how to pass the line count to the Threadgroup

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils; 

int lines = FileUtils.readLines(new File("path to data file")).size(); 
vars.put("lines", String.valueOf(lines));
```

this lines variable I want to use to thread group how I can achieve this
please help me on this

Updating the output of Debugsampler

```
JMeterVariables:
JMeterThread.last_sample_ok=true
JMeterThread.pack=org.apache.jmeter.threads.SamplePackage@1e59359f
START.HMS=081505
START.MS=1449648905577
START.YMD=20151209
TESTSTART.MS=1449652524822
applicationname=test
buildinfo=../data/Test.csv
env=Test
lines=77
package=.zip
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you can use Debug sampler  to verify if you are successfully getting the desired value in your variable.

Second, you can simply call the this variable just like other user defined variables in JMeter. Put ${lines} where required.

If you still face any issues, then let me know in comment or edit your question to add further details.

Comment: updated the Debugsampler output in the question section,i am able to see the value in Debugsampler output.still i am not able to access 'lines' value in ThreadGroup as LoopCount

Comment: I am not sure if you can access the variable from bean shell sampler in Threadgroup (loop count) as beanshell sampler is supposed to run after wards. In my experience, you can do it from either Test Plan or User defined variables at Root of test plan. To generate required number you can try different JMeter functions and see if that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot configure Thread Group loop count this way as it is being populated on JMeter launch. Here are the options:

1. Use [Loop Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller) instead, it is possible to set the number of loops via variable
2. Define "Loop Count" in Thread Group as a property, like `${__P(loops,)}`. In that case you can get CSV file lines count before the test i.e. using the relevant OS command like:

   - `type c:\temp\file.csv | find /c /v "~~~"` - for Windows
   - `cat /tmp/file.csv | wc -l` for *nix

   and pass the resulting value to JMeter via -J command line key as:

   ```
   jmeter -Jloops=XX -t /path/to/your/testplan.jmx ...
   ```

See [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) for more information on JMeter properties and ways of setting and overriding them.